# Using GUI buttons to scale shapes, if statement needed

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have been given a GUI which creates a random bunch of shapes, the user then has the choice to scale them up or down with the **+** or the **-** button. However, when I click either of those buttons it calls the scale method:

```
public void scale(boolean sign) {
    shapes.scale(10,false);
}
```

How do I make it so the **+** button would scale it up, and the **-** button would scale it down? I know it's something to do with an if statement somewhere but I am really struggling.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need an if statement here.

Comment: So how would I solve this issue then?

Comment: you need to acces + and - button on the keyboard and write an action performed event.

Comment: @kaanyilmaz and how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an if statement here.

You need different `actionPerformed` methods like:

```
plusB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        scale(true); // Assuming it scales up for true, and down for false.
    }
});

minusB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        scale(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is that he doesn't know what to do in the `scale()` method

Comment: Is it good practice to add a new ActionListener to every object you need an ActionListener on? I would have just implemented the class and used an if statement on the event.

Comment: @SaviourSelf That depends on you. I like this way. The method will only be called for its specific object.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply @Hackerdarshi but Draken is correct, I really am struggling with the scale() method. I added this code into my work, and it threw a load of errors, no variable plus B, no constructor () and also cannot find symbol ActionEvent()